# DetailsView converts TextBoxes empty string to null

Tags: asp.net, binding, detailsview, string

I have a basic ASP.NET Web Forms application.

I give the user the possibility to create the records by using a  **Web Form** and to update them by using a **DetailsView**.

The web form stores the empty field on the **TextBoxes** as **empty strin**g in the DB correctly.

The **DetailsView** instead stores them as **null** fields in the DB.

Moreover in the **DetailsView_ItemUpdated** event if I check the **e.newvalues** and **e.oldvalues** arguments the corresponding fields are null as well (throwing an exception) that means the data are already sent as null to the server upon submit.

In the **DetailsView** I use templates and I set all Update parameters in the **SQLDataSource** as **ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"**.

**SQLDataSource parameter**:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="SHELF" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
```

**DetailsView**

```
 <asp:DetailsView runat="server" 
                    ID="GvProductDetail" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="rowid" 
                    DataSourceID="ProductDetailData" 
                    OnItemUpdated="gvProductDetail_ItemUpdated">

 <asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>Stock Shelf &nbsp;</HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <%# Eval("Shelf") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtShelf"  Text='<%# Bind("Shelf") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Is that possible that Bind converts the empty values to null? I thought it was enough to set the UpdateParameters rule not to convert empty string to null but apprently there is some other surprise. anybody might help?

Comment: You might find something from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170021/convertemptystringtonull-false-and-yet-the-conversion-still-happens) related post

Comment: @EmmanuelN, thanks for your answer. I already had a look before at that post and it has no answer

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by placing ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" to every `<asp:TemplateField>` containing `<asp:TextBox>`:

```
<asp:TemplateField ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"> 
   <HeaderTemplate>Stock Shelf &nbsp;</HeaderTemplate> 
   <ItemTemplate>&nbsp;<%# Eval("Shelf") %></ItemTemplate> 
   <EditItemTemplate> 
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtShelf" Text='<%# Bind("Shelf") %>' >
     </asp:TextBox> 
   </EditItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```